# How do I make Python, QT, and Webkit work on a headless server?

Tags: python, qt, webkit, headless, headless-browser

I have Debian Linux server that I use for a variety of things.  I want it to be able to do some web-scraping jobs I need done regularly.

This code can be [found here](http://bit.ly/QeqvzX).

```
import sys  
from PyQt4.QtGui import *  
from PyQt4.QtCore import *  
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *  

class Render(QWebPage):  
  def __init__(self, url):  
    self.app = QApplication(sys.argv, False)  # Line updated based on mata's answer
    QWebPage.__init__(self)  
    self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)  
    self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))  
    self.app.exec_()  

  def _loadFinished(self, result):  
    self.frame = self.mainFrame()  
    self.app.quit()
```

A simple test of it would look like this:

```
url = 'http://example.com'
print Render(url).frame.toHtml()
```

On the call to the constructor it dies with this message (it's printed to stdout, not an uncaught exception).

```
: cannot connect to X server
```

How can I use Python (2.7), QT4, and Webkit on a headless server?  Nothing ever needs to be displayed, so I can tweek any settings or anything that need to be tweeked.

I've looked into alternatives, but this is the best fit for me and my projects.  If I did have to install an X server, how could I do it with minimal overhead?

Comment: Can you avoid including QtGui?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

One of the constructors of `QApplication` takes a boolean argument [`GUIenabled`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qapplication.html#QApplication-2). 
If you use that, you can instantiante QAppliaction without an X server, but you can't create QWidgets.

So in this case the only option is to use a virtual X server like [Xvfb](http://www.xfree86.org/4.0.1/Xvfb.1.html) to render the GUI.

Xvfb can be installed and run using these commands (assuming you have apt-get installed).  The code in the original question is in a file called `render.py`.

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb
xvfb-run python render.py
```

Comment: It gave me "QWidget: Cannot create a QWidget when no GUI is being used".  Do you have an idea how to fix it?  I'll check out Xvfb, just in case.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really check it and I somehow seemed to remember that you just can't show widgets in headless mode but instantiate them. So if you need to use Qt, you'll have to go with Xvfb.

Comment: xvfb works great!  I was worried I'd have to install all of X11, and have a server running.  Thanks!  I updated your answer with what worked for me.

Comment: @mata Where did you read that the constructor for QApplication takes an argument GUIenabled? I can't find anything about that.

Comment: @GreySage - I've updated the link. Note that this is only valid for PyQt4, on PyQt5 that argument is not supported anymore, probably because it doesn't make a lot of sense in the first place. Better to use QCoreApplication instead.

Comment: Except that webkit relies on the gui application, even if you don't use any widgets it will complain if you try to use the QCoreApplication.

Comment: @GreySage The GUIEnabled parameter doesn't help eitter in that situation, so you either need to use a virtual X server, or for PyQt5 you can try the `-platform minmal` approach as suggested below.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work too well when the application is moderately complex?: https://bitbucket.org/brainstorm/flatcam/addon/pipelines/home#!/results/17

Answer (score 6):

On gitlab CI/CD. Adding `['-platform', 'minimal']` and using xvfb didn't work for me. Instead I use `QT_QPA_PLATFORM: "offscreen"` variable.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55442821/6000005

Comment: This worked for me and seems to be the current solution. I have used `xvfb` in the past (years), which doesn't do it any more, but setting the platform target as described here does.

Answer (score 5):

If PyQt5 is an option, Qt 5 has the "minimal" platform plugin.

To use it, modify the argv passed to QApplication to include `['-platform', 'minimal']`.

Answer (score 1):

If all you are trying to do is get the webpage, you could use

```
import urllib
urllib.urlopen('http://example.com').read()
```

Comment: Good general answer, but I like to have the JavaScript.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes.  HTML, CSS, JavaScript, images, etc.  It's exactly like going to the site in Chrome or Safari (they both use WebKit).

Comment: It seems I may have misunderstood what you were trying to do. Are you wanting to actually display the webpage? Your example led me to believe that you only wanted the HTML.

Comment: Python WebKit lets you do querys on the page (CSS2-like selectors), execute JavaScript, etc.  You could do what I want with the HTML and BeuatifulSoup but I like the completeness.

Comment: OK, then @mata's version is what you want.

Comment: The main limiter for BeautifulSoup is the fact that it ignores JavaScript, which is why the OP was lead to webkit, just like me I'm sure.

Answer (score 1):

[phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) is a webkit based solution. runs headless as well. try it out.

If you are keen on using webkit yourself you could also try the pyslide version of qt.