# Create a pyqt build in GitLab

Tags: python-3.x, build, pyqt4, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm making a program in `pyqt4`, using `python3.4` and host on Gitlab. When I'm trying to make a build this fails.
This is the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file form my project:

```
 before_script:
     - apt-get update -qy
     - apt-get install -y python3 python3-dev python3-pip python3-pyqt4
     - export DISPLAY=:0.0

test:
    script:
        - python3 main.py
```

The error is: `main.py: cannot connect to X server: 0.0`. I am trying without `export DISPLAY=:0.0` and nothing

Comment: That error means you do not have a graphical environment running. It would be helpful if we could see the python script (or parts of it) to help you with this further.

Comment: It looks like this thread addresses your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13215120/how-do-i-make-python-qt-and-webkit-work-on-a-headless-server

Comment: The code can you find [here](https://github.com/ragnarok22/encriptednetwork)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If PyQt5 is an option, Qt 5 has the "minimal" platform plugin.
To use it, modify the argv passed to QApplication to include ['-platform', 'minimal'].

(reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35355906/829568)

For PyQt4, you could use a virtual X Server:

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb
xvfb-run python render.py
```

(reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13215192/829568)

Answer (score 3):

I've tried:

- include `['-platform', 'minimal']` in sys.argv for QApplication : Failed
- tried xvfb : Got `xvfb-run: error: xauth command not found` (even after setting the PATH)

But `QT_QPA_PLATFORM: "offscreen"` work like a charm and saved the day.

example:

```
pytest:
  image: python:3.6
  variables:
    QT_QPA_PLATFORM: "offscreen"
  script:
    - pytest tests/
```

Thanks to [steve](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50972823/6000005)

Answer (score 0):

Would like to suggest an alternative answer to [azzamasa's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55442821/12868283)

1. Using `pytest` with `pytest-qt`, [add a pytest option](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/example/simple.html#pass-different-values-to-a-test-function-depending-on-command-line-options) (preferably in conftest.py) to indicate if the application should show or not:

   ```
   def pytest_addoption(parser):
       parser.addoption('--show-gui', action='store_true')
   ```
2. [Use qapp_args fixture](https://pytest-qt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pytestqt/plugin.html#qapp_args) to provide the needed arguments `-platform offscreen`:

   ```
   @pytest.fixture(scope="session")
   def qapp_args(show_gui: bool):
       if not show_gui:
           empty_arg_stands_for_exe_path = ''
           return [empty_arg_stands_for_exe_path, '-platform', 'offscreen']
       return []
   ```