# travis-ci pyqt application creation failure

Tags: python, pyqt, travis-ci, pyqt5

To test my code that is a plugin for a pyqt5 application, I'm writing tests that create dummy QApplication objects.

However, whenever I try to create a QApplication code locally works as expected but segfaults in travis.

I pinpointed the issue to the following line:

```
qapp = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
```

This is the error I'm getting (taken from the travis log):

```
tests/idaplugin/test_plugin.py::test_plugin_creation /home/travis/.travis/job_stages: line 53:  2382 Aborted                 (core dumped) PYTHONPATH=. py.test ./${PROJECT} ./tests/${PROJECT} --verbose --cov-report= --cov=$PROJECT
```

Here is the travis-ci job: https://travis-ci.org/nirizr/rematch/jobs/219490893

And here's the snippet of the test:

```
def test_plugin_creation():
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
    qapp = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    # test be here, requires a QApp to function 
    plugin = plugin_rematch.PLUGIN_ENTRY()

    ... extra test code removed ...
```

Is this an issue with travis or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to run xvfb on Travis to be able to execute graphical applications (if you don't need any GUI, use `QCoreApplication` instead).

You can either [follow Travis' docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/gui-and-headless-browsers/#Using-xvfb-to-Run-Tests-That-Require-a-GUI), or (since it looks like you're using pytest), use my [pytest-xvfb plugin](https://github.com/The-Compiler/pytest-xvfb).

By the way: pytest's `-s` flag (to not hide output from "passing" tests) is quite useful when debugging issues like this.

Comment: Thanks! Can I use QCoreApplication if I don't need to see any GUI but do plan on using different visible widgets and pytest-qt to automate user interaction with those widgets?

Comment: No, you'll need to use Xvfb if you want to use QtWidgets.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

On gitlab CI/CD you can use `QT_QPA_PLATFORM: "offscreen"`

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55442821/6000005